# Replace text in multiple Google Docs of a specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I've tried variations of code to get this to work, but nothing is working. Can anyone help?

```
    function pleaseWork() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("IDofFolder").getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    doc.replaceText("User Services", "Customer Success");
  }
  Logger.log("Done")
}
```

Comment: Although in my environment, I confirmed that your script worked, for example, when `doc.replaceText("User Services", "Customer Success");` is modified to `doc.getBody().replaceText("User Services", "Customer Success");`, what result will you obtain? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike. Thank you. I realized that the docs in my folder are not Google Docs, but Microsoft Word (.docx) files, so I changed the code to: .getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD);

Comment: function pleaseWork() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("IDofFolder").getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    doc.getBody().replaceText("User Services", "Customer Success");
  }
  Logger.log("Done")
}

Comment: I'm getting an error on this line: var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());                              The error states: "Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later. (line 6, file "Code")"

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when the script is put to the comment, I think that the readability is low. When you put the script, please add it to your question. By the way, when I saw your script in your comment, it seems that the script is different from your question. How about this? And, `DocumentApp.openById` can be used for Google Document. But in your script in your comment, the files of `MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD` are used. How about this?

Comment: Thank you, @Tanaike. I didn't know how to add more code so I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350963/adjust-google-apps-script-code-for-pdf-files-or-word-files-find-and-replace  I want to be able to bulk replace text in PDF or Word files within a Google Drive folder, but just changing the MIME type doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you add more information in your question, you can achieve it by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65334592/edit) button.